# applet to Jframe

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

I've followed kilobolt's tutorial to make a game (http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-2-creating-a-game-i.html) then changed it. I've used applet but now I want to turn it into JFrame.

**What I've done:**

1- I've imported and extended JFrame instead of Applet.

2- I've changed init method into a constructor and added

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Use the event dispatch thread to build the UI for thread-safety.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AltMain(); //AltMain is the name of my main class.
        }
    });
}
```

I've copied this code from somewhere and I don't exactly know what this does. I will probably just use this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new AltMain();
}
```

**What I couldn't:**

These required some changing: (My first priority right now)

```
base = getDocumentBase();
```

and

```
bg = getImage(base, "data/bg space.jpg");
```

GetImage and GetDocumentBase give me "undefined for the type AltMain" error.

How can I fix these? Is there any JFrame equivalent for these? Also since I cannot run the program I'm not sure if anything else is necessary. Is there anything else I must do?

These are my other methods:

```
public void run(){
public void start(){
public void update(Graphics g){
public void paint(Graphics g){
```

How am i supposed to connect them.

The code is very long so I've just posted a summary. If necessary I can write more of the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the functions do rather than just copy-pasting them and hoping for the best.

But the main idea is this: an applet (which uses a JApplet) has several functions that are called automatially.

An application (which uses a JFrame) only has the main() method as an entry point. It doesn't automagically call any other functions for you, so if you have existing functions (the JApplet functions), you have to call them from the main() method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

If I'm not mistaking the main method creates an instance of the AltMain Class so the constructor class is called. I just don't know why SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { and public void run() under it, are there.

I don't think  KeyPressed and keyReleased methods are part of the applet. Should I add these to the main() method? I can't try it yet due to the other errors.
    run();
    start();
    update();
    paint();
I don't what must be the parameters of the update() and paint() methods.

Comment: You just asked about a dozen questions so it's hard to answer in a comment, but I stand by my statement that you need to understand what each method does. SwingUtilities makes sure you're running on the EDT. The keyPressed() methods have nothing to do with either JFrame or JApplet. They are part of a KeyListener that is automatically called when a component receives a KeyEvent. What are the errors on the other methods? You need to read the basic tutorials to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've told the problems in my question. These are: `getDocumentBase` and `getImage` give me errors. Right now these are my first priority. They were part of the applet and now don't work. 

It is important to know the code but i learn best by trying and changing the code once it starts to work. 

Correct me if I'm wrong please: `update(Graphics g){` and `paint(Graphics g){` are not part of the applet. They are being called by `repaint();`. I think I can call start() at the the end of init() (it is now the constructor) and i can call run() at the end of start().

Comment: What is the error? Can you find update() and paint() in the API for JApplet?

Comment: `getDocumentBase` and `getImage` give "The method getDocumentBase() is undefined for the type AltMain" and "The method getImage(URL, String) is undefined for the type AltMain" errors respectively. 

I don't understand what you mean by finding the methods. I've checked it and JApplet have them but I don't want to use JApplet unless it can be used by JRE in an executable file (which is the reason I want to switch to JFrame from applet. Repaint at the end of the run() method seems to work fine though.